# How to upload a file using HTTP PUT operation

Tags: http, put

I have a tar file available in my local machine & I want to upload this file to a server using HTTP PUT. Can some body help with the format?

This is what I trying to execute: I have a file in my local server under /var/log/latest.tar & I am trying to upload this to server 10.129.134.138 under /tmp/rest

set response [::http::geturl 10.129.134.138:1001/tmp/rest -method PUT -headers {Content-Type:octet-stream;  filename:"/var/log/latest.tar"; "Content-Disposition: attachment" } ]

::http::26

But I am getting a response with error as Invalid request format for content-type. Probably I have misused header content. Please guide

set res [http::data $p ]

..
"code": 1000,
"title": "Invalid request format",
"detail": "Request header must include a valid Content-Type attribute"
..

Answer (score 0):

> I have a tar file available in my local machine & I want to upload
>   this file to a server using HTTP PUT. Can some body help with the
>   format?

You can use cURL:

```
curl http://myserver --upload-file file.tar
```

Comment: I am specifically in need of using HTTP